# Python function sort and manipulate based on Arguments

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, arguments

```
def some_generator(sum_limit, index_value):
    """
    >>> list(some_generator(20, 4))
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 11], [3, 5, 15], [4, 5, 9]]

    """
    a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 11],
         [3, 5, 15], [4, 5, 9], [4, 6, 12], [1, 5, 19]]
    for i in a:
        if sum(i) <= sum_limit or i[0] < index_value:
            yield i
        else:
            break


def foo(_generator):
    """
    >>> foo(some_generator(20, 4))
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3, 5, 15], [3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 11]]
    """
    x = list(_generator)
    return sorted(x)
```

1) For the function `some_generator`, how do I achieve: if `sum_limit` is `None`, then change the if condition

`if sum(i) <= sum_limit or i[0] < index_value:`

to

`if i[0] < index_value:`

or vice versa (if `index_value` is `None`, then change the if condition to:

`if sum(i) < sum_limit:`

2) For the function `foo`, how do I sort based on an argument? (For example, I may wish to sort the list based on last element's value, or I may wish to sort based on each elements sum.)

Comment: One question per post, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a logical `and` in your condition and for sorting you can use `key` argument in `sorted` function :

```
def some_generator(iterator ,sum_limit, index_value):
    """
    >>> list(some_generator(20, 4))
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 11], [3, 5, 15], [4, 5, 9]]

    """
    for i in iterator:
        if (sum_limit and (sum(i) <= sum_limit)) or  (index_value and (i[0] < index_value)):
            yield i
        else:
            break


def foo(_generator, custom_key = None):
    """
    >>> foo(some_generator(20, 4))
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3, 5, 15], [3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 11]]
    """
    x = list(_generator)
    return sorted(x,key= custom_key)

iterator = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 11],
         [3, 5, 15], [4, 5, 9], [4, 6, 12], [1, 5, 19]]

print foo(some_generator(iterator,20, 4), custom_key=sum)
```

Note that since in python 2.X you can compare the difference type objects like `None` and `integer` since every integer is larger than None and since `sum_limit` and `index_vallue` are supposed to be grater than your items if they be None it will be evaluated as False, thus the condition will be depends on other part, and you don't need to check the validity if `sum_limit` and `index_value`.

```
>>> 0>None
True
>>> 4>None
True
>>> -4>None
True
>>> 4<None
False
>>> 0<None
False
>>> -2<None
False
```

Comment: @blackened You can pass the key-index in `some_generator` and sort the `i` in each iteration based on that index.

Comment: Did not understand the first part, what's the problem with using an `and`?

Comment: @Kasramvd Perhaps I am missing something. Each element is also a list. How do I include the option to sort final list of lists based on inner list sums (or products) which will passable by an (optional) argument?

Comment: @tglaria No problem, it's correct too. But is redundant here.

Comment: @blackened So instead of index pass the key as a function. And for sorting based on sum of nested lists you can pass `sum` function.

Comment: @Kasramvd Why do I get “NameError: name 'sorting_index' is not defined” error?

Comment: Different types are unorderable by default in python 3. In python 3, `1 < None` raises a `TypeError`. I mention this as the question is specifically tagged `python-3.x`.

Comment: @Dunes Thanks for mentioning that, I think I missed the ` python 3` tag.

Comment: @blackened Sorry change I missed to update some_generator function, Try now.

Comment: @Kasramvd, as Dunes mentionned in my answer, if `sum_limit==0`, then `sum_limit and sum(i) <= sum_limit` is false even if `sum(i) < 0`, which shouldn't be (check my code).

Comment: @tglaria Yep, it's because of different priority of `and` ,`<=`, you can put the second part in parenthesis.

Comment: @Kasramvd if `sum(i)= -1` and `sum_limit = 0`, then it would be expected that the 'condition' evaluated to `True`, but the condition `(sum_limit and (sum(i) <= sum_limit))` evaluates to '0', which is not the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

1) You could just use

```
if ((sum_limit is not None) and sum(i) <= sum_limit) or ((index_value is not None)) and i[0] < index_value):
```

if `sum_limit == None`, then the evaluation `sum(i) <= sum_limit` is skipped.
Same thing with `index_value`

Example:

```
print (None and xyz) or (True or xyz)
```

It will print 'None' and no error will raise if xyz doesn't exist.

2) Just read the manual. Add the 'key' variable to your `sorted` function. google python + sort

Comment: Does not `x = list(_generator)` pull the data?

Comment: The problem with just using the boolean value of an object is that some objects will be considered false, despite being valid values (eg. zero). You should be more explicit and use `sum_limit is not None and sum(i) <= sum_limit`.